# Can pointed sets category have an arrow that points to the same set?

Tags: category-theory

In the category of *pointed sets* [p.17, [Awodey](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199587361)], can there be an arrow that points to the same set but with a different distinguishing element?

I.e., if I have a set $A=\{1,2,3\}$, can there an arrow $f: (A,1) \to (A,2)$?

Comment: A constant map $f = 2$ for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Any set function $f:A \to A$ with $f(1)=2$ gives such an arrow.

Two pointed sets which are the same set with a different distinguishing element aren't any *more* different than two totally different pointed sets (which you can obviously have functions between) — they just aren't the same object as each other.

Comment: Awesome, just want to double check!